# Pandas: Isolating very specific data within a str.contain method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am using multiple lists like this:

```
restaurants = ['MCDONALD', 'DONUT', 'FOOD COURT', 'WHATABURGER']
```

These lists simply pull those keyboards from a "Description" dataframe from my bank csv file. Each of those items has a cooresponding debit amount in the same row that I want to isolate. I also want to rename the dataframe in the process to show something like:

```
Restaurants: $43.00
```

Currently when I run:

```
restaurant_total = df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains('|'.join(restaurants), flags = re.I, regex = True)].reset_index(drop = True).sum()
```

it prints out:

```
Description    MCDONALD'S F24712              LANE...
Debit                                                     43.00
Credit                                                         0
dtype: object
[Finished in 0.683s]
```

I would like to get rid of the default descriptions (mcdonalds part) and replace it with something more suitable and then ONLY show the debit amount.

Comment: I've put an answer for you but you should really read [mcve] and how to ask a good pandas question. (you can search it) do that and you'll get good quality answers rather quickly.

Comment: Will do , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a helper column and do a groupby

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Description' : ['McDonalds','WhatABurger','Donuts',"Pepe's"],
                  'debit' : [50, 33,250,3.99]})

restaurants = ['MCDONALD', 'DONUT', 'FOOD COURT', 'WHATABURGER']

df.loc[
    df["Description"].str.contains("|".join(restaurants), case=False, regex=True),
    "Type",
] = "Restuarant"


new_df = df.groupby('Type')['debit'].sum().to_frame()

print(new_df)

            debit
Type             
Restuarant  333.0
```